# How to draw a line between two views in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I need help with drawing a simple line between two Outline Views in Swift 3 (Xcode 8).
My situation:

```
Main ViewController
|--- Main View
     |--- Outline View
     |--- Outline View
```

So I Need help to get the coordinates of both Outline Views and draw a line with them (the line itself is not that difficult, more to get the coordinates). The goal is to draw a line (programmatically) that ***connects*** both Outline Views (f.ex. from one edge to the other, or from the top, ...).

I already tried following:

```
class Line: NSView{
    var origin = CGPoint()
    var destination = CGPoint()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint){
        self.origin = fromPoint
        self.destination = toPoint

        super.init(frame: CGRect(origin: fromPoint, size: CGSize(width: destination.x - origin.x, height: destination.y - origin.y)))
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect){
        let myPath = NSBezierPath()

        myPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: origin.x, y: origin.y))
        myPath.line(to: CGPoint(x: destination.x - origin.x, y: destination.y - origin.y))
        myPath.stroke()
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

       let line = Line(fromPoint: self.view.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.view.viewWithTag(1)), toPoint: self.view.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.view.viewWithTag(2)))
        view.addSubview(line)
    }
}
```

But that didn't do anything.

I would appreciate your help!

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps I'm begging the question, but any reason why you don't use a separator-style `NSBox` (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Box/Tasks/UsingToCreateVisualSep.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000860-BAJEAIEE) and lay it out in Interface Builder? You could also subclass it if you want to do custom drawing....

Comment: @NSGod Thanks, but I think you misunderstood my question, probably my mistake - I will edit it. I don't want to separate them, but just to draw a line that connects them both (like from one edge to the other).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now solved my problem (more or less) as following:

```
class Line: NSView{
    var fromPoint = CGPoint()
    var toPoint = CGPoint()

    func setPoints(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint){
        self.fromPoint = fromPoint
        self.toPoint = toPoint
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let path = NSBezierPath()

        NSColor.green.setFill()
        path.move(to: fromPoint)
        path.line(to: toPoint)
        path.stroke()
    }
}


class ViewController: NSViewController{
     override function viewDidLoad(){
          super.viewDidLoad()

          let subview3 = Line(frame: self.view.bounds)
          subview3.setPoints(fromPoint: subview1.convert(CGPoint(x: subview1.bounds.maxX, y: subview1.bounds.maxY), to: self.view), toPoint: subview2.convert(CGPoint(x: subview2.bounds.minX, y: subview2.bounds.minY), to: self.view))
          self.view.addSubview(subview3)
     }
}
```

I need to know how to do this on runtime. Do I always have to create a new view in order to draw a path?

A full example:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  DrawConnectViews
//
//  Created by T M on 17.06.17.
//  Copyright © 2017 TM. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let subview1 = CustomViewWithColor(frame: NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 10.0), size: CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)))
        let subview2 = CustomViewWithColor(frame: NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 360.0, y: 360.0), size: CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)))

        // create a subview programatically:
        let subview3 = Line(frame: self.view.bounds)
        subview3.setPoints(fromPoint: subview1.convert(CGPoint(x: subview1.bounds.maxX, y: subview1.bounds.maxY), to: self.view), toPoint: subview2.convert(CGPoint(x: subview2.bounds.minX, y: subview2.bounds.minY), to: self.view))
        self.view.addSubview(subview3)

        subview1.setColor(color: NSColor.red)
        subview2.setColor(color: NSColor.blue)
        self.view.addSubview(subview1)
        self.view.addSubview(subview2)
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }



}

class CustomViewWithColor: NSView{
    var color = NSColor()

    func setColor(color: NSColor){
        self.color = color
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let path = NSBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
        self.color.setFill()
        path.fill()



    }
}


class Line: NSView{
    var fromPoint = CGPoint()
    var toPoint = CGPoint()

    func setPoints(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint){
        self.fromPoint = fromPoint
        self.toPoint = toPoint
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let path = NSBezierPath()

        NSColor.green.setFill()
        path.move(to: fromPoint)
        path.line(to: toPoint)
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

That produces following: 
[Output of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJQQL.png)

Comment: It does not work in iOS11, iOS12, iOS13 and iOS14. It is just draw two views with different colors and fill view background in black. It is not draw a green line anymore. Maybe you can update your answer for Swift 5

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people will think that this is overkill, but what I do is add a subview whose background is the line color, whose height is constrained to the desired line thickness, and whose leading and trailing edges are constrained to the superview's leading and trailing edges. This ensures that the border will *always* adjust with the superview's size, which is why adding a border as a *layer* or customizing the view's `draw(in:)` to draw the border as a path don't work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  See my comment above to NSGod; I wanted to connect the both Views with a line instead of separating them.

Comment: No problem :-) Do you have any idea for that?